# Collecting data from PLC every 1 sec - would like to get the data when the data changes

Tags: mysql, vb.net, modbus

I am currently collecting data from my PLC with easyModbus (using Visual Basic) every 1 second with a timer and later I want to insert data to a database. My goal is to only refresh data in my program when a value changes inside of the PLC.

For example: I have 4 LEDs, 1-green 2-yellow 3-red 4-blue, and I have a timer which measures the elapsed time from when the red light comes on to when it turns of.

I want to log the time data to a database....when the error happened...when the error if fixed. But with my 1 sec refresh it is writing my data every 1 sec and I need it to only write the data when it changed...and I also don't want to ask the PLC every single second because I don't need to.

```
Public Sub Refresh_btn_Click() Handles Refresh_btn.Click
    Dim ComError = 0 'Set comm error flag to 0

    Dim Ipaddress As String
    Ipaddress = "127.0.0.1"

    Dim Portaddress As String
    Portaddress = "502"


    Dim ModbusClient As EasyModbus.ModbusClient = New EasyModbus.ModbusClient(Ipaddress, Portaddress) 'Ip address and port Text box = Ip on form

    Try
        ModbusClient.Connect() 'Connect to PLC
    Catch ex As Exception   'What to do when error occurs
        Status_lbl.BackColor = Color.Red
        Status_lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
        Status_lbl.Text = "Error!"
        ComError = 1 'Set comm error flag to 1
    End Try
    If ComError = 0 Then
        Status_lbl.BackColor = Color.Green
        Status_lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
        Status_lbl.Text = "No Error!"

        'First line Andon
        Dim Registers As Integer()
        Registers = ModbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 10)
        'Indexing Registers starting with null

        If Registers(0) = 0 Then
            GreenSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            YellowSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            RedSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            BlueSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        End If

        If Registers(0) = 1 Then
            GreenSIGN.BackColor = Color.Green
        Else
            GreenSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        End If

        If Registers(0) = 2 Then
            YellowSIGN.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        Else
            YellowSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        End If

        If Registers(0) = 3 Then
            RedSIGN.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            RedSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        End If

        If Registers(0) = 4 Then
            BlueSIGN.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Else
            BlueSIGN.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        End If
    End If

    ModbusClient.Disconnect()
    'Timer for downtime Static Start-Stop
    Static start_time As DateTime = Now
    Static stop_time As DateTime = Now
    Static start_time2 As DateTime = Now
    Static stop_time2 As DateTime = Now
    Dim elapsed_time As TimeSpan

    'Only Red Andon
    'If for Red andon For Line XXX
    If RedSIGN.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        stop_time = Now
        elapsed_time = stop_time.Subtract(start_time)
        lbl_elapsed_red.Text = elapsed_time.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
    Else
        lbl_elapsed_red.Text = "Ok"
        start_time = Now
    End If


    'Only Blue Andon
    'If for Blue andon For Line XXX
    If BlueSIGN.BackColor = Color.Blue Then
        stop_time2 = Now
        elapsed_time = stop_time2.Subtract(start_time2)
        lbl_elapsed_blue.Text = elapsed_time.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")


    Else
        lbl_elapsed_blue.Text = "Ok"
        start_time2 = Now


    End If

    'Connectin MySQL

    'Try
    '    Dim SQL As String 'SQL Command String
    '    Dim objCmd As New MySqlCommand 'Command
    '    'Connection String to the SQL Database
    '    Dim Con = New MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;database=andon")
    '    'SQL Statement - All values must be set for the table
    '    SQL = "INSERT INTO test_andon VALUES ('" & Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") & "', '" & Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") & "','" & "@dummy" & "', '" & Now.ToString("start_time2") & "', '" & "@dummy" & "', '" & "@dummy" & "')"
    '    Con.Open() 'Open the database connection
    '    objCmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, Con) 'Set the command
    '    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'Execute the SQL command
    '    Con.Close() 'Close the database connection
    'Catch ex As Exception 'What to do when an error occurs
    '    Status_lbl.BackColor = Color.Red
    '    Status_lbl.ForeColor = Color.White
    '    Status_lbl.Text = "Database Error Blue vége!"
    'End Try


End Sub




'Timer reping
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Interval = 100
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Call Sub() Refresh_btn_Click()
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) If there is some way for your PLC to send a signal to the computer when a change happens then you can use that, otherwise you will have to poll the PLC. 2) I strongly recommend that you store dates in the database using the datetime type rather than a string. 3) It looks like you are only looking at the value of `Registers(0)`, so you just need to store its old value and if the new value is different *then* you add to the database and update the old value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. in fact a am going to look for about 60+ registers in the end If maybe you could give me some examples for your 3rd point, that would be nice. i can poll the plc, but my main problem is, when i log the data to my database every second it is going to make a new row and i just need to log when the red light started and ended i dont need the inbetween time data (and i would like the startdate and enddate to be in 1 row and for the next time the red lights coms on in another row) and then i'll calculate the elapsed time...i dont really know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the state of the red light and check if the new value is different from the old value. If it is, then write to the database and update the old value, otherwise do nothing.

For example, pretend that the incoming value related to the red light is `r(t)`:

```
Imports System.Timers

Module Module1

    Dim t As Integer = 0
    Dim r() As Integer = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
    Dim prevValue As Integer = Integer.MinValue

    Sub tock(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        Dim val = r(t)

        Console.Write(val.ToString() & " ")

        If val <> prevValue Then
            Console.WriteLine("Write to database.")
            prevValue = val
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Do nothing.")
        End If

        t = (t + 1) Mod r.Length

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim tim As New Timers.Timer With {.Interval = 1000, .AutoReset = True}
        AddHandler tim.Elapsed, AddressOf tock
        tim.Start()

        Console.WriteLine("Tocking... press enter to quit.")

        Console.ReadLine()
        tim.Stop()
        tim.Dispose()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
Tocking... press enter to quit.
0 Write to database.
1 Write to database.
1 Do nothing.
1 Do nothing.
1 Do nothing.
0 Write to database.
0 Do nothing.
0 Do nothing.
0 Do nothing.
0 Do nothing.
1 Write to database.
0 Write to database.
1 Write to database.
1 Do nothing.
[Carries on until enter is pressed.]
```

Notice that the first value makes a write-to-database because `prevValue` was initialised to a value which `r(t)` will never have. After that, write-to-database only happens when `r(t)` <> `r(t-1)`.

Comment: I just need to make it in win forms

Comment: @DávidHorváth My example used a System.Timers.Timer - you might find it better to use a Windows.Forms.Timer which I think is what you were using originally. They are a little bit different.

Comment: Sorry i am really a beginner and it is not working for me in win form...if its not a big problem can you give this solution in windows form app?

Comment: @DávidHorváth It will be at least a few hours before I will have enough time to do that, so you might want to keep trying.

Comment: I think i just figured it out, thank you so much for your help. It seems like it is working, just need my query and it is going to do what i wanted. Thanks again.

Comment: What is **CRC** or **LRC**, Why are you comparing all the data ?

Comment: @dsgdfg I think your comment has ended up on the wrong post.